# From where should I call alert boxes, loading windows - Controllers or Services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am building a Angular Js (Ionic) app. So while reading the best practices in angularjs development lot of sources said that controllers should not be used for Dom interactions. Currently the ionicloading and ionicpopup calls are made from the controllers. Do these considered as DOM interactions, if yes where this suppose to be added ?

Comment: I don't know what you want to know but most of the blogs must say avoid `jQuery` for DOM manipulation. You should use `directives` instead. I don't know what this line means `controllers should not be used for Dom interactions` ?

Comment: http://trochette.github.io/Angular-Design-Patterns-Best-Practices/#/keep_controllers_simple

Comment: You should read https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive in your case.

Comment: So Is it ok to use popup and loading services from controllers itself ?

Comment: `services` are meant to be designed for separate piece of code which should not depend upon controller. A controller may dependent on a service. You can inject your service in your controller and use it or you can create a `directive` as well.

Comment: it would be great if you could help in one more doubt, So consider a case I have to query something from server and if response is error, I should show a popup. Where should i show that controller or services ?

Comment: You can directly use `$ionicPopup` in your `controller`. It's a predefined `service` of ionic

Answer (score 2):

showing/hiding popup etc...from controller is perfectly acceptable. 
e.g. you have a button on UI. You can use ng-click="onButtonClick()" and invoke the popup to disply some message.

When we say "avoid DOM manipulation within controller"  - don't do stuff like document.getElementById("#someId").someDOMOperation() or $("#someId").someDOMOperation(). you better write a directive and use it on UI.

Answer (score 1):

Actually [$ionicLoading](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicLoading/) and [$ionicPopup](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/) are services which are allowed to maninulate the DOM in specific cases like these (modals and such).

In your controllers you use these services and invoke the methods you need but the DOM manipulation happens in the service.

This is from Misko Hevery (Father of Angular JS)